# WooCommerce Market place vendors list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce with WCFM to create an online marketplace with these structures

In the first page, I need to show all categories of products, it´s ok working using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', 'hide_empty_categories', 10, 1 );
function hide_empty_categories ( $hide_empty ) {    
    $hide_empty  =  FALSE;
    // You can add other logic here too
    return $hide_empty;
}
```

When clicking on category I need to show all vendors for theses category, today are showing all products

When clicking on the vendor I need to show all products for the vendor.

Any idea how to do this?

Updated: To solve this question and for further reference add these code in functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','shop_filter_cat');    
function shop_filter_cat($query) {  
    $cate = get_queried_object();
    $cateID = $cate->term_id;

    if (is_product_category()) {            
      if( isset($_POST['spbv']) || '' !== $_POST['spbv']) {         
            echo do_shortcode("[wcfm_stores has_orderby='' search_category='". $cateID ."' category='' has_product='yes' per_row='5' ]");   
            remove_filter('woocommerce_product_loop_start');
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working URL Please?

Comment: https://seubairro.officevb.com.br/ @Aroganz  look "LANCHES" category i want show two vendors. Thank you

Comment: Hope this shall help you https://wclovers.com/knowledgebase/wcfm-marketplace-single-product-multi-vendor/